# SQL COUNT(*) in one table including zero values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL table (With more columns, but it is not important)

```
CREATE TABLE `test_results` (
`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_time` datetime,
`altpn` varchar(60),
`error1` int,
`error2` int,
`error3` int,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Data can be like: id, 2016-06-16 14:26:02, 9513 400, 590, 0, 0.

And on this table Im running this SQL query:

```
SELECT date(test_results.date_time) AS date, test_results.altpn as PN, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM test_results 
WHERE (test_results.error1 = 1000 OR test_results.error1 = 1001 OR test_results.error2 = 1000 OR test_results.error2 = 1001 OR test_results.error3 = 1000 OR test_results.error3 = 1001) 
GROUP BY date(test_results.date_time), test_results.altpn 
ORDER BY date(test_results.date_time), test_results.altpn
```

This works OK, but I also need to know dates, when `COUNT(*)` is zero. I saw few topics about `LEFT JOIN`, but I am not able to modify codes to work with this  table.

Comment: Removed sql-server tag based on syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use WHERE, you filter rows with other error codes out and they cannot be counted. Instead, select all rows as usual and LEFT JOIN to a table where zero-rows do not exist:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_results t1
LEFT JOIN test_results t2 ON t2.id=t1.id
  AND 
  (t2.error1 = 1000 OR t2.error1 = 1001 OR t2.error2 = 1000 
  OR t2.error2 = 1001 OR t2.error3 = 1000 OR t2.error3 = 1001)
```

As you see, the result set includes rows with errors of 1000/1001 and NULL values for other errors. Now, simply group and count them:

```
SELECT date(t1.date_time) AS date, t1.altpn as PN, COUNT(t2.id) AS count 
FROM test_results t1
LEFT JOIN test_results t2 ON t2.id=t1.id
  AND 
  (t2.error1 = 1000 OR t2.error1 = 1001 OR t2.error2 = 1000 
  OR t2.error2 = 1001 OR t2.error3 = 1000 OR t2.error3 = 1001) 
GROUP BY date(t1.date_time), t1.altpn 
ORDER BY date(t1.date_time), t1.altpn
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c6236/4

Comment: Thanks for working code and more thanks for explanation :-).